# UiPath pdf table scraping into a DataTable type

Tags: pdf, datatable, uipath

Can I somehow import a table from **pdf to** a UiPath **DataTable**?

I can do it via loading it to a string array and after that splitting it. But I hope so there is a better and more safe solution to get a table from PDF.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the **[Read PDF Text](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/read-pdf-text)** activity.

As it's often changing, it does really make sense to give you a tutorial here about how you add it to UiPath and what parameters you currently have. Overall all info you can find on the [official detailed tutorial](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/read-pdf-files).

Basically this activity gives you the easy way of extracting data and managing it.

If the result is not okay you will need to switch to the OCR activity with nearly the same name. This one reads the data visually. But from what you gave here, I would not recommend you that.

There are many other activities out there, like extracting it into an Excel Workbook. So simply try out what you need.